# Redirecting controller control to sub-controller

Tags: php, fuelphp, fuelphp-routing

I'm using FuelPHP for my website. Currently, I've the following structure:

```
-folder1
  -FILEHERE.php
-folder2
...
-fuel
  -app
    -classes
      -controller
        -learn.php
        -folder1.php
-public
```

I've created a controller in `fuel->classes->controller` with the name learn.php. Now what I want is this:
If the person visits `http://example.com/learn` -> this controller fires up (learn.php).
I want to add a sub-controller and throw control to that whenever there is a next directory request. i.e.:
http://example.com/learn/folder1 should throw control to `folder1.php` in `fuel->classes->controller`.

How do I do this? I've checked the methods action_* but they don't look flexible.
Also, once the user visits something like: `http://example.com/learn/folder1/FILEHERE`
It should load the content file from `folder1->FILEHERE.php` (see the directory layout above)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using FuelPHP's routing functionality. Which is documented [here](http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/routing.html).

Your basic route config for the `folder1` controller might look something like this:

```
'learn/folder1'   => 'folder1/index',
```

The documentation outlines more complex examples as well if needed.